# How do I change the mode of perspective?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working on a scene that, currently, is much more convenient when the view is.. not the correct perspective.

There's a word for this, but I have no idea how to phrase it and my tries to look it up has all come up with weird results. (usually directions on how to make your view point from a certain direction)

This has probably already been answered here, so please bear with me; I just cannot find anything that has to do with the problem I'm having.

I drew a photo to make it easy: (excuse my crappy mouse-drawing skills)

[image: dumb drawing]

Thanks!

Comment: ...the word is "orthographic"? Also the menu "view > view persp/ortho" will help you. If you use "emulate numpad", just use the "5" on the keyboard

Comment: @BeardWix if you are starting with blender, there is a manual that is quite helpful https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/index.html and use the resources listed on this page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: see in particular https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html?highlight=orthographic

Comment: also, why the face above is sad in both situations, shouldn't it be happy on the right...? :D

Comment: For a "crappy mouse drawing," it is pretty good!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If this is what you're asking, you can switch from ***User Perspective*** to ***Orthographic*** by using the Numpad <kbd>5</kbd> key.  The perspective type is given in the upper left hand corner of the 3D view.

The differences can be found here: [What are the differences between Orthographic and Perspective views?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/648/what-are-the-differences-between-orthographic-and-perspective-views)

Essentially, Orthographic is a "non-real-world" view in which all dimensions have the same scale... i.e. objects that are farther away appear to be the same size as objects that are near-field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Aren't you the guy that helped me on my last question as well?

Comment: @BeardWix - Possibly... glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking to *render* in orthographic mode, you can just switch the camera from perspective projection to orthographic (a type of parallel projection) in the camera properties, under "Lens".  Note that you'll probably need to reposition your camera afterward, as it will have changed your frustum.

[image: camera settings dialog]

If you only want to temporarily preview the scene that way, use numpad-5 as @bertmoog said.

Comment: Nice. Not the answer to my question, but a good tip nontheless!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it manually in:

*3D View header> View > View Persp/Ortho*