# How do I change my orthographic view?

Tags: orthographic

What keys do I need to click to go into user ortho and left ortho?

Comment: The 5 key toggles ortho and perspective. The 1,3,&7 keys change views.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86969/how-do-i-change-the-mode-of-perspective. Specify what exactly do you want please - to enter preset orthographic views or orthographic mode in general.

Comment: @EthanBodine SE auto blocked you from asking new question because all of yours so far have been low quality. (ditto my [other comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100717/what-keys-do-i-click-to-go-into-back-orthographic-mode#comment179445_100717) for this one too)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need numpad 5, not just the 5 key. If you do not have a numpad, go to user preferences and check the box that says "emulate numpad", so then you can use your number keys.