# How do I get the x, y bounds covered by the camera?

Tags: scripting, camera

I need to get the bounds of the camera view, in other words a rect of (x, y) coordinates so that I know anything outside these coordinates will be outside the camera view. I would like to do this via a script if this is possible?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6891/599

Comment: It is possible, you can remodel the camera (not that hard) and then get a vectorspace, spanned by the camera origin and the vectors to the 4 points of the rectangle. Every point in the vectorspace is inside the camera, every other is outside. (Modeled Camera: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5248/)

Comment: x,y bounds don't work I think because the space that the camera looks at is no cuboid but a pyramid that isn't quadratic (don't know the word), so you would have infinite x,y bounds

Comment: Highly relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/649/245