# Bones act different comparing camera perspective and Z view

Tags: 3d-view, bones, camera

I have camera with the following configuration

[image]

I expect of camera perspective view and Z view to be the same, but I see different positions of bones

I'm not changing the position of anything during switching between view points

Camera perspective:
[image]

Orthographic view point:
[image]

EDIT:
Top perspective Z view:
[image]
How I can get different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd image is in orthographic view instead of perspective view.

You can change it to perspective view simply via clicking the grid icon like button
[image]

If you are not sure what orthographic and perspective views are you can read about it here

[What are the differences between Orthographic and Perspective views?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/648/what-are-the-differences-between-orthographic-and-perspective-views)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about it, but also using perspective view, it's not exactly the same, Does it make sense? I added top perspective view

Comment: See default view of the camera is perspective only, if you want perfectly same result as the camera view, you will need to line up your view ( which is also a camera that you move around) with the camera perfectly other wise it will not be same as the camera. 
A simple way to understand is look at something with one eye closed and then quickly open your other eye and close the first one, you will notice that the thing you were looking appears to have "moved" slightly in relation to other objects.